# How to use textures from texture tab with material shading

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I found a book of an older version of blender to learn from. We are suppose to make texture in the texture tab and apply it later on the object. But many features are not available in the latest versions of blender.
Can anyone explain how to approach this thing.

Secondly, how do we use a texture, for example cloud texture from texture tab, as input to any node group for shading.

[image: Passage of the book]

[image: cloud texture]

Comment: The textures in the _Texture_ tab are not for use in the materials, you can use them in the _Displacement Modifier_ or in the _Flow_ object of a smoke simulation for example. For the materials, you have the _Texture_ nodes, like _Noise_, _Voronoi_, _Musgrave_ etc. in the _Shader Editor_. The _Clouds_ texture from the _Texture_ tab is actually the standard _Noise_ texture in the materials, by the way.

Comment: Thanks man...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't tell if this is the way it was always meant to be, but a workaround could be to use the Texture Paint workspace. On the left panel you could create a new image and name it anything you want. In the Shader Editor, you add an Image Texture, browse to select the image you've named earlier and connect it with the Base Color of the Principled BSDF. At this point, in the Texture Paint workspace, you could paint using the earlier created Clouds brush from the Texture Properties either Image Editor or in the 3D Viewport, for perspective painting.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShehzadAdeel Please consider to mark this answer as accepted, which helps other users to easily find the solution they're looking for. Read here for more info: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)